# How to redirect a live data stream adding to it another header and returning it on demand? (PHP)

Tags: php, proxy, header, stream

I have a url like http://localhost:8020/stream.flv

On request to my php sctipt I want to return (be something like a proxy) all data I can get from that URL (so I mean my php code should get data from that url and give it to user) and my header and my beginning of file.

So I have my header and some data I want to write in the beginning of response like

```
# content headers
        header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");        
        # FLV file format header
        if($seekPos != 0) 
        {
        print('FLV');
        print(pack('C', 1));
        print(pack('C', 1));
        print(pack('N', 9));
        print(pack('N', 9));
    }
```

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I used to do something very similar, I also forwarded all headers from the original flv to the end user but you can just remove that section if you want to set your own.

```
$video = fopen(URL, "rb");

// Forward headers, $http_response_header is populated by fopen call
foreach ($http_response_header AS $header) {
    header($header);
}

// Output contents of flv
while (!feof($video)) {
    print (fgets($video));
}

fclose($video);
```

Comment: but problem is on that side http://localhost:8020/stream.flv the stream is live and so infinit... so Any notes for such case?

Comment: Hmmm fopen doesn't download the whole file, and feof will in theory continue reading the file until the end - ie never in the case of a stream? At least that's what I'm thinking but could well be wrong - give it a try!

Comment: dude your answer saved my day :) but i have a question to you, how you check if the connected link is stopped?

Answer (score 0):

See the manual entries for [fopen](http://www.php.net/fopen) and [fread](http://www.php.net/fread).

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished this using libcurl,

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8020/stream.flv';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: but problem is on that side localhost:8020/stream.flv the stream is live and so infinit... so Any notes for such case?